# What is this pipe - should I be worried?

Tags: plumbing, furnace, framing, structural

We found it behind a wall, it is a bit more than 10 inches wide it has about an 3/4 inch of concrete between metal.

It was jaggedly broke off on the bottom in the basement ceiling. 
It is also jaggedly broken off in the attic, it looks like it used go through the roof, because there is patch there. It does not seem to be supported by anything.  it is almost in the middle of the house. It is not near much plumbing or anything.

It seems really heavy duty and does not seem to have any connections.  What was it for? Could this be a problem in the future? Could it fall? Could someone have messed with the structural integrity of the house?

[image: Pipe in Basement Ceiling] 
[image: Main Behind wall on main floor]

Comment: How old is this house?  Could be a heavy duty pipe for a stove or old furnace.

Comment: What do you mean "concrete between metal"?  Where's themetal?

Comment: What is in the area in the basement?  Is there a furnace, wood burning stove, water heater, etc. near it?  Is there a similar hole or patch on the floor directly below?

Comment: Put a magnet up to it... you'll see that the magnet sticks to it because it's cast iron, not concrete

Comment: I was wrong about the metal, it is some sort of shiny paint or enamel or something.

Answer (score 1):

It an abandoned sewage and vent pipe. It was replaced, and the roof patched where it used to exit. Apparently they never got around to finishing the job, or just figured it wasn't any problem leaving it like it was. As to whether it's safe, since it hasn't fallen yet, it probably won't. But, you could get a ladder and pull on it to make sure. And no, there isn't a structural integrity issue. I'd finish off the basement ceiling to hide it.

Comment: I live in earthquake country, and would pull such a pipe in a second.  No sense in letting it crash thorough the ceiling.

Comment: Too big for a dwv pipe?

Comment: Well, it's not a chimney, as it's single layer.

Comment: It's cast-iron pipe. It probably weights a million billion pounds

Comment: It could be asbestos-cement flue pipe. If so, it will be difficult/expensive to dispose of legally, at least in developed countries. Best to ensure it's secure in place and leave it. What ever you do, DO NOT cut or grind this stuff!!

Comment: Getting tested for asbestos, results in 36 hours.